# How to copy xml entire elements, attributes and data to new xml file with specific id using python

Tags: python, parsing, copy

**Below is my sample xml source file**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.sample.com/xml/catalog" catalog-id="sample-catalog">
<product product-id="214146430">
<online-flag>false</online-flag>
<online-flag site-id="sample_ae">false</online-flag>
<available-flag>true</available-flag>
<searchable-flag>true</searchable-flag>
<tax-class-id>standard</tax-class-id>
<page-attributes/>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="adultsize">L</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</product>
<product product-id="214146123">
<online-flag>false</online-flag>
<online-flag site-id="sample_ae">false</online-flag>
<available-flag>true</available-flag>
<searchable-flag>true</searchable-flag>
<tax-class-id>standard</tax-class-id>
<page-attributes/>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="adultsize">L</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</product>
</catalog>
```

I want to copy only product id 214146430 to
New xml file and it should look like below

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns="http://www.sample.com/xml/catalog" catalog-id="sample-catalog">
<product product-id="214146430">
<online-flag>false</online-flag>
<online-flag site-id="sample_ae">false</online-flag>
<available-flag>true</available-flag>
<searchable-flag>true</searchable-flag>
<tax-class-id>standard</tax-class-id>
<page-attributes/>
<custom-attributes>
<custom-attribute attribute-id="adultsize">L</custom-attribute>
</custom-attributes>
</product>
</catalog>
```

I am currently using xml.etree.ElementTree and xml.dom but no luck
but it is just copying the entire xml which is is not expected

Below is my python code

```html
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('Development/product_data_parser/emporio-imoprt-test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
```

**Thank so much in advance for your help**

Comment: Please share your code and someone will surely let you know what's wrong

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response
I have edit the post including my current basic python code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this although this solution might be specific to your use-case:-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

# A list of product IDs that you want to keep
keep = ['214146430']

# Figure out the namespace (used in tag matching later)
def getnamespace(root):
    m = re.match(r'\{.*\}', root.tag)
    return m.group(0) if m is not None else ''

tree = ET.parse('Development/product_data_parser/emporio-imoprt-test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
namespace = getnamespace(root)
for elem in root.findall(f'{namespace}product'):
    if elem.attrib['product-id'] not in keep:
        root.remove(elem)
print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
```

Comment: This is 100% the answer I've been looking for.
I have modified your answer with much simplified namespace


Again, thanks brother. Godbless